# Android: Java Net Socket Exception inside AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I am getting the following exception when i run my android app:
I am getting inside the asynctask but logging this exception.

```
03-15 16:49:21.456  16854-16892/com.ashwinbhy.phpwrite W/Ashwin﹕ java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I have included this permissions inside my manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.internet"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.access_network_state"/>
```

The code is:

```
 try {

                URL url = new URL("http://10.0.0.2/tt.php");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("bus_id", busid)
                        .appendQueryParameter("lat", lat)
                        .appendQueryParameter("lon", lon);

                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                conn.connect();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.w("Ashwin",e.toString()+"inside the exception log");
                return "error";
            }
```

Can someone please point where am i going wrong ?

I am addding the log:

```
03-15 17:15:42.140    9003-9034/com.ashwinbhy.phpwrite I/System.out﹕ open:http://10.0.0.2/tt.php
03-15 17:15:42.141    9003-9034/com.ashwinbhy.phpwrite D/libc-netbsd﹕ [getaddrinfo]: hostname=10.0.0.2; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
03-15 17:15:42.141    9003-9034/com.ashwinbhy.phpwrite D/libc-netbsd﹕ [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
03-15 17:15:42.142    9003-9034/com.ashwinbhy.phpwrite I/System.out﹕ [CDS][DNS] getAllByNameImpl netId = 0
03-15 17:15:42.142    9003-9034/com.ashwinbhy.phpwrite D/libc-netbsd﹕ [getaddrinfo]: hostname=10.0.0.2; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
03-15 17:15:42.142    9003-9034/com.ashwinbhy.phpwrite D/libc-netbsd﹕ [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
03-15 17:15:42.143    9003-9034/com.ashwinbhy.phpwrite I/System.out﹕ [CDS]rx timeout:10000
03-15 17:15:42.143    9003-9034/com.ashwinbhy.phpwrite I/System.out﹕ [socket][3] connection /10.0.0.2:80;LocalPort=55951(15000)
03-15 17:15:42.143    9003-9034/com.ashwinbhy.phpwrite I/System.out﹕ [CDS]connect[/10.0.0.2:80] tm:15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting proper case for permissions. They are case sensitive.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Update**

Your IP is also wrong. It should be, `10.0.2.2`. So your URL will become,

```
http://10.0.2.2/tt.php
```

It should work fine on the emulator.

Comment: Thank you.
I am not getting exception but my page is not accessible still.

I am not getting any error.

Comment: i am running it on local network 10.0.0.2/tt.php works fine from my browser

Comment: i am conncted to same wifi it works fine from my mobile browser but not working from app. the post request is not going.

Comment: For mobile you need to give the IP starting with something like `192.168.xxx.xxx`.

Comment: Can you please see the log i have added in the comments.

Comment: If it is working in mobile browser it should also work in my mobile app right ??

Comment: Ideally it should work. Try change the IP as said in the above comment.

Comment: Code is wrong somewhere i tried another code and it works fine now :